# Rails: associations - User has_many Model1, and Model1 has_many Model2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

A "User" has many "datasets". A "dataset" has many "graphs". How should this be modeled using Rails Associations? **Is anything wrong with this setup?**

Basically a user can upload many datasets. For each dataset, a user can create several graphs from it. I will need to "get all graphs for a user" and "get all graphs for a dataset".

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :datasets
    has_many :graphs, through: :datasets
end

class Dataset < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :graphs
end

class Graph < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dataset
  belongs_to :user # Do I need this line? Or is it implicit since it belongs to dataset?
end
```

**Tables**

Users

```
id, email
```

Datasets

```
id, user_id, name
```

Graphs

```
id, dataset_id, type # Do I need "user_id" in here also?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks OK apart from the Graph belonging to User part. If Rails supported belongs_to :through, it could be used here, but as it is, having the user_id on the Graph table is not necessary - a Graph's user can simply be retrieved through the Dataset.

Comment: So if I have a user_id, like "3", how can I get all graphs for that user? Would `all_graphs = User.find(3).graphs` work?

Comment: It would, because you still have the association from User to Graphs. Going back the other way from a Graph to a User, you could delegate the :user call in the Graph model (eg. `delegate :user, to: :dataset`) which means you could call `Graph.find(3).user` (which would be a shortcut for `Graph.find(3).dataset.user`).